# Module isomorphic to a flat module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a flat $A$-module, and $N$ a $A$-module isomorphic to $M$, what can we say about the flatness of $N$?

Comment: $N$ is flat? Or what do you want to hear?

Comment: why is $N$ flat?

Comment: If $M\cong N$ as $A$-modules, then for any $A$-module $P$, $P\otimes_A M\cong P\otimes_A N$.

Comment: Dear Jr., here is a meta-rule for you. Whenever mathematicians define a property P that some objects in a category may or may not have, you can be sure that if an object has property P, then any isomorphic object also has property P.

Comment: Dear Georges , is there a formal proof of your statement? I mean, only using abstract category theory, does one could reach that conclusion?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:M\to N$ be an isomorphism of $A$-modules, and let $P$ be an arbitrary $A$-module. Then $P\times M\to P\otimes_A N$, $(p,m)\mapsto p\otimes f(m)$ is $A$-bilinear, hence we get an induced well-defined homomorphism
$$\operatorname{id}\otimes f:P\otimes_A M\to P\otimes_A N, p\otimes m\mapsto p\otimes f(m).$$
In the same way, we have an inverse homomorphism $\operatorname{id}\otimes f^{-1}$, such that $P\otimes_A M\cong P\otimes_A N$.

Now $M$ being flat means that if $g:P\to P'$ is an injective morphism of $A$-modules, $g\otimes\operatorname{id}:P\otimes_A M\to P'\otimes_A M$ is, too. But then the map
$$P\otimes_AN\xrightarrow{\sim}P\otimes_AM\xrightarrow{g\otimes\operatorname{id}}P'\otimes_AM\xrightarrow{\sim}P'\otimes_A N$$
is an injective $A$-homomorphism, which proves the flatness of $N$.

As for your question regarding Georges' answer, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. In general, one defines these properties *such that* they stay invariant under isomorphism in the respective category. But looking for a proof of this, as Georges calls it, *meta-rule*, wouldn't really make sense to me.