# Faithful flatness is preserved by isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $D$ be a ring and let $M$ and $N$ be two modules over $D$.
Suppose that $M$ is a faithfully ﬂat $D-$module and $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic.
Prove or disprove that $N$ is a faithfully flat $D-$module?

Comment: You surely have some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez See the answer in the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125155/module-isomorphic-to-a-flat-module?rq=1

Comment: To be honest, I find it quite extraordinary that one can be able to understand a notion such as flatness or faithful flatness and not get the immediate observation that they are invariant under isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Given an injective linear map $\;i:E\longrightarrow F$, and the isomorphism $\;u:M\longrightarrow N$, consider the commutative diagram:
\begin{alignat}{2}\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
E\otimes_D M&\xrightarrow{~i\,\otimes\,\id_M~}{}F\otimes_D M \\
\id_E\otimes f\downarrow\qquad & \hspace{5em}\downarrow \id_F\otimes u\\[-1ex]
E\otimes_D N&\xrightarrow{~i\,\otimes\,\id_N~}F\otimes_D N
\end{alignat}